# How to change output from object class name + hashcode to string output based on custom class I used

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to Java and Im practicing creating classes, objects and getting variables from classes.
I created a class Factory which includes 2 string variables and one array of object from different class called Item which includes 2 string variables. In my main program I want to sout variables from Factory class. I managed to print name and address but getItem() obviously won't print getName() string from Item class. I tried overriding with toString in Factory class but it doesn't work with this type of custom class I guess. What can I do in this situation?

Class Factory:

```
public class Factory {

     public static final int MAX_ODABRANIARTIKLI = 3;

     String name;
     String address;
     Item[] items = new Item[MAX_ODABRANIARTIKLI];


public Factory(String name, String address, Item[] items) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.items = items;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public Item[] getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public void setItems(Item[] items) {
    this.items = items;
}
}
```

class Item:

```
public class Item {

    String name;
    String category;
}
public Item(String name, String category) {
    this.name = name;
    this.category = category;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}
}
```

main code:

```
import hr.java.production.model.Factory;

public class Main {

public static final int MAX_TVORNICA = 2;

public static void main(String[] args) {

Factory[] tvornice = new Factory[MAX_TVORNICA];

System.out.println("Unijeli ste sljedeće tvornice:");
    for(Factory factory : tvornice){
       ispisTvornica(factory);
    }
}

public static void ispisTvornica(Factory factory){

    System.out.println("Naziv: " + factory.getName());
    System.out.println("Web adresa: " + factory.getAddress());
    System.out.println("Odabrani artikli: " + factory.getItems());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override toString() method in Item class which returns name then you can use Arrays.toString(factory.getItems())

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try This

### **Factory.Java**

```
public class Factory {
    public static final int MAX_ODABRANIARTIKLI = 3;

    String name;
    String address;
    Item[] items = new Item[MAX_ODABRANIARTIKLI];

    public Factory(String name, String address, Item[] items) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public Item[] getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setItems(Item[] items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

### **Item.java**

```
public class Item {
    String name;
    String category;

    public Item(String name, String category) {
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item [name=" + name + "]";
    }
    
    
}
```

### **Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static final int MAX_TVORNICA = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        
        Factory[] tvornice = new Factory[MAX_TVORNICA];

        System.out.println("Unijeli ste sljedeće tvornice:");

        Item[] items = { new Item("Joy", "category_Joy"), new Item("Roy", "category_Roy") };

        tvornice[0] = new Factory("Jems", "ABC", items);
        tvornice[1] = new Factory("ivuksan", "XYZ", items);

        for (Factory factory : tvornice) {
            ispisTvornica(factory, i++);
        }
        
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        
        for (Factory factory : tvornice) {
            ispisTvornicaAnother(factory);
        }
    }

    public static void ispisTvornica(Factory factory, int i) {

        System.out.println("Naziv: " + factory.getName());
        System.out.println("Web adresa: " + factory.getAddress());
        System.out.println("Odabrani artikli: " +factory.getItems()[i]);
    }
    
    public static void ispisTvornicaAnother(Factory factory) {

        System.out.println("Naziv: " + factory.getName());
        System.out.println("Web adresa: " + factory.getAddress());
        for(Item item : factory.getItems())
            System.out.println("Odabrani artikli: " + item);
    }
}
```

I define two function:

1. ispisTvornica() function print for each iteration 1 by 1 item name present in Item class
2. ispisTvornicaAnother() function print for each iteration it print all items name.

### **Output:-**

```
Unijeli ste sljedeće tvornice:
Naziv: Jems
Web adresa: ABC
Odabrani artikli: Item [name=Joy]
Naziv: ivuksan
Web adresa: XYZ
Odabrani artikli: Item [name=Roy]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Naziv: Jems
Web adresa: ABC
Odabrani artikli: Item [name=Joy]
Odabrani artikli: Item [name=Roy]
Naziv: ivuksan
Web adresa: XYZ
Odabrani artikli: Item [name=Joy]
Odabrani artikli: Item [name=Roy]
```